# Why is my program running twice on my Server?

Tags: java, server, tcp, client

I am writing tcp client-server program. When the client types "Hello" the server returns a list of files and directories of his current directory. When the client types "FileDownload " it downloads the selected file from the server.
When I type "Hello" it works fine, but when I type "FileDownload ", on the server side it runs twice the `else if(received.contains("FileDownload"))` block. Because of this the server is sending twice the data which is causing other issues on the client side.

Here is the server code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        
            ServerSocket servSock = new ServerSocket(1333);
            
            String received="";
            String[] s = null;
            File[] f1;
            int i=0;
            
            File f=new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
            f1=f.listFiles();
            
            for(File f2:f1) {
                if(f2.isDirectory())
                    System.out.println(f2.getName() + "\t<DIR>\t" + i);
                if(f2.isFile()) 
                    System.out.println(f2.getName() + "\t<FILE>\t" + i);
                i++;
            }
            
                while (true) { 
                    
                    Socket client = servSock.accept();
                    
                    InputStream in = client.getInputStream();
                    OutputStream out = client.getOutputStream();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(out, true);
                    s=f.list();
                    
                    while(true) {

                        received = reader.readLine();
                        if(received.equals("END")) break;
                        
                        if(received.equals("Hello")) {
                            System.out.println("Hello-Start");

                            int length=f1.length;
                            pw.println(length);
                            i=0;
                            for(File f2:f1) {
                                if(f2.isDirectory())
                                    pw.println(f2.getName() + "\t<DIR>\t" + i);
                                if(f2.isFile()) 
                                    pw.println(f2.getName() + "\t<FILE>\t" + i);
                                i++;
                            }
                            pw.println("Options: " + "\tFileDownload <FID>" + "\tFileUpload <name>" + "\tChangeFolder <name>");
                            System.out.println("Hello-End");

                        }
                        else if(received.contains("FileDownload")) {
                            System.out.println("FileDownload-Start");

                            int j=-1;
                            try {
                                j=Integer.parseInt(received.substring(13).trim());
                            }catch(NumberFormatException e) { 
                                System.err.println("error: " + e);
                            }
                            
                            if(j>0 && j<s.length) {
                                FileInputStream fi=new FileInputStream(s[j]);
                                byte[] b=new byte[1024];
                                System.out.println("file: "+s[j]);

                                pw.println(s[j]);
                                fi.read(b,0,b.length);
                                out.write(b,0,b.length);
                                System.out.println("FileDownload-End");
                            }
                        }
```

Here is the client code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        if ((args.length != 2))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Parameter(s): <Server> <Port>");
        
        Socket socket = new Socket(args[0], Integer.parseInt(args[1]));
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
        OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(out, true);

        
        while(true) {
            String msg="", received="";
            String length;
            
            msg = sc.nextLine();
            pw.println(msg);
            
            if(msg.equals("END")) break; 
            
                if(poraka.equals("Hello")) {
                    System.out.println();
                    length = reader.readLine();
                    for(int i=0;i<Integer.parseInt(length);i++) {
                        received = reader.readLine();
                        System.out.println(received);
                    }
                    System.out.println("\n"+reader.readLine());
                }
                else if(msg.contains("FileDownload")) {
                    System.out.println("FileDownload-Start");
                    pw.println(msg);
                    byte[] b=new byte[1024];
                    File file=new File(reader.readLine().trim());
                    System.out.println(file.getName().trim());
                    FileOutputStream fo=new FileOutputStream("D:\\Eclipse WorkSpace\\proekt\\src\\client\\"+file.getName().trim());
                    System.out.println("file: "+file.getName().trim());

                    in.read(b,0,b.length);
                    fo.write(b,0,b.length);
                    System.out.println("FileDownload-End");
                }
```

I could not find what's causing this issue, so any help possible would be very highly appreciated!

Comment: What have you done to try to find the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because your client requests the data twice:

```
        msg = sc.nextLine();
        pw.println(msg);  // <-- this is the first time
```

and then later

```
            else if(msg.contains("FileDownload")) {
                System.out.println("FileDownload-Start");
                pw.println(msg);  // <-- this is the second time
```